# Como traer datos registrados en una fecha y hora determianda

Tags: php, mysql

Un saludo para todos, tengo lo siguiente:

En mi base de datos guardo registros todos los días, adicional el sistema también me guarda la fecha y hora que son dos variables que se llaman: (fecha_retiro, hora).

Tengo la siguiente consulta:

```
SELECT id_reit,cliente,codigo_reit,descri_reit,cantidad_reit,fecha_retiro,
       quien_retiro,ubicacion,estante,nivel,hora, 
       SUM(cantidad_reit) AS sumacantidadtw 
FROM retiro_items 
WHERE cliente='$acliente' 
AND categoria='Operacion' 
AND fecha_retiro BETWEEN '2021-06-10' AND '2021-06-11'
AND hora BETWEEN '06:00' AND '06:00'
```

El problema es que también quiero que me traiga los datos registrados no solo en la fecha actual por ejemplo: 10/06/2021 sino que también me traiga los registrados desde las 6:00 am del 10/06/2021 hasta las 06:00 am del otro día 11/06/2021. serian los registros de las ultimas 24 horas.

De que forma podría hacer esto? por fecha me sirve perfecto pero no se como hacerlo también por la variable hora.

Cualquier ayuda me podría servir de gran utilidad.

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Eso depende mucho de la estructura de la tabla, la `fecha_retiro` tiene hora, minutos y segundos ??

Comment: typo de valor en la columna.

Comment: Hola @Excorpion la variable fecha_retiro solo guarda la fecha en este formato: año-mes-día y tengo la hora variable que se llama hora que guarda la hora normal.

Comment: eso cambia el query entonces...

Comment: Hola @FranciscoNúñez-TodoPoderoso el tipo de valor es varchar tanto la fecha_retiro como la hora.

Comment: @estrada Entonces tienes una columna con la hora?? Has agregado eso a la consulta ?? O no ?? para que edites la publicación con el intento. Además agrega la estructura de la tabla y un ejemplo de fila a consultar.

Comment: Asi es tengo la columna con la hora, el campo se llama hora en base de datos.

Comment: Hola @Excorpion ya acabo de editar mi pregunta y le agregue la variable hora y compara ahora por un rango de hora predeterminado de 06:00 am a 06:00 am pero ya no me trae registros, como hago para que traiga los datos de 06:00 am del día actual hasta las 06:00 am del día siguiente?

Comment: @estrada Quisiera saber por que tienes el DATE separado en fecha y hora, sería mucho más simple hacer un `BETWEEN '2021-06-10 06:00:00' AND '2021-06-11 06:00:00'`

Comment: [Revisa apartado 2) de este post](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-between). Cuando usas `BETWEEN` conviene castear la cadena con la fecha y hora que quieres comparar al tipo de dato de la(s) columna(s). De hecho, un aspecto fundamental que no leo en tu pregunta es **de qué tipo es la columna `fecha_retiro` y la columna `hora`**. Por cierto, si declaras `fecha_retiro` del tipo `DATETIME` puedes usarla para guardar tanto la fecha como la hora. Ahorrarías espacio, eventuales índices, simplificarías las consultas y darías menos margen a posibles errores en la introducción de los datos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

creo haber encontrado una solución.

Viendo que tienes DATE and TIME por separados, recomiendo unirlos del siguiente modo:

```
STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(fecha, ' ', hora), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') as fechaHoras
```

De este modo, hemos creado una nueva columna resultado, como timestamp.
Ahora, podemos usarla para filtrar entre las fechas y horas asignadas.

```
AND fechaHoras BETWEEN '2021-06-10 06:00:00' AND '2021-06-11 06:00:00'
```

Comment: Hola @Excorpion en mi consulta actual como puedo aplicar la primera linea que comentas: STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(fecha_retiro, ' ', hora), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') as fechaHoras

Comment: Eso es una línea extra dentro de la consulta... en la parte del select. Puedes cambiar fecha_retiro por esa, o añadirla como nueva.

Comment: Entendido, voy a realizar eso que indicas a ver si funciona.

Comment: Avisame cualquier cosa

Comment: Hola @Excorpion implemente lo que mencionas a la consulta pero aun no funciona, ahora no me trae nada: SELECT id_reit,cliente,codigo_reit,descri_reit,cantidad_reit,fecha_retiro,quien_retiro,ubicacion,estante,nivel,hora, SUM(cantidad_reit) AS sumacantidadtw,
STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(fecha_retiro, ' ', hora), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') as fechaHoras 
FROM retiro_items WHERE cliente='$acliente' AND categoria='Operacion' 
AND fechaHoras BETWEEN '2021-06-10 06:00' AND '2021-06-11 06:00'

Comment: No se si importe, pero no has añadido los segundos. Prueba primero quitando los demás filtros de WHERE, y prueba solo la fechaHoras. Si no obtienes un registro, revisa que haya uno al que llamar, y confirma.

Answer (score -2):

```
 AND fecha_retiro BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 24 HOUR) AND now()
```

Intenta con este, este trae el registro de 24 horas atras de la fecha y hora actual

Comment: El OP requiere el intervalo de 24 horas, pero de fechas especificas. Como dice, del 10 desde las 6am, hasta el 11 a las 6am.

Comment: Hola @Excorpion asi es, específicamente lo que estoy buscando hacer es que por ejemplo del día de hoy me muestre todo de 06:00 am hasta el día de mañana 06:00 am